# Every time user clicks on the button I need the next value from the array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently trying to loop an array in a function. This function supposed to be used for a button, which gives every time a different value from the array when its pressed.

```
var list=['DEFAULT','ADVANCED','DEVELOPMENT'];
```

Every time user clicks on the button i need the next value from the array. (when its "DEVELOPMENT", next should be "DEFAULT"). Is it possible to do it without using a global variable ?

Comment: What is wrong with using global variable?

Comment: @Maxqueue: Maybe nothing, but I imagine he doesn't quite know what you mean.  I personally dislike using globals in Javascript; there are too many gotchas.

Comment: This link should be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator

Comment: Linq comes to mind.  There are libraries that implement Linq in Javascript, and you can use `Take()`.

Comment: `var newWord = list[list.indexOf('DEVELOPMENT')+1 === list.length ? 0 : list.indexOf('DEVELOPMENT') + 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fine with changing array [chiliNUT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362228/477420) would work (`shift`/`push` to implement circular buffer).

Alternatively you can keep current selection and loop that with `%`. To avoid global variables wrap counter in a function to capture value.

Sample (assuming usage of JQuery, you can find equivalent `addEventListener` code yourself):

```
  $(function()
  {
       // outside of click handler to be able to preserve values between clicks 
       var current = 0;
       $("button.next").click(function()
        {
            alert(list[current]);
            current = (current + 1) % list.length;
        });
  }

  <button class="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this. `shift` pulls off the first element. `push` sends it to the back.

```
var list=['DEFAULT','ADVANCED','DEVELOPMENT'];
function nextWord() {
var word=list.shift();
list.push(word);
console.log(word);
return word;
}

nextWord();//DEFAULT
nextWord();//ADVANCED
nextWord();//DEVELOPMENT
nextWord();//DEFAULT
nextWord();//ADVANCED
nextWord();//DEVELOPMENT
//...
```

`<button onclick=nextWord()>Next Word</button>`